# Animating Multiple Divs On Window Resize

Tags: jquery

So I'm working on a personal website, and am having some issues with positioning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PklrV.png

Ideally, that's what I'd like the site to look like. Right now, however, whenever the window gets resized the buttons popping off the main center image won't stay with it. My idea to fix this would be to set everything where it should be at a 1,000px window and then have a function that triggers at load and whenever it's resized that moves the buttons ('resized size' - 1000) pixels to the left.

If anyone can help get this to work, or point out where this codes going awry, I'd be incredibly appreciative.

Relevant HTML;

```
<div class = "mobile">
    <div id= "titlehead">
        <img src = "./images/Tilehead.png" alt="headtitle">
    </div>
    <div id= "illustrationb">
        <a href = "Illustrations.html">
            <img src = "./images/IllustrationBanner.png" 
            onmouseover="this.src='./images/Bannerc-1.png'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='./images/IllustrationBanner.png'"></a>
    </div>
    <div id= "aboutb">
        <a href = "Illustrations.html">
            <img src = "./images/Banner-4.png" 
            onmouseover="this.src='./images/Bannerc-4.png'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='./images/Banner-4.png'"></a>
    </div>
    <div id= "photob">
        <a href = "Illustrations.html">
            <img src = "./images/Banner-3.png" 
            onmouseover="this.src='./images/Bannerc-2.png'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='./images/Banner-3.png'"></a>
    </div>
    <div id= "infob">
        <a href = "Illustrations.html">
            <img src = "./images/Banner-2.png" 
            onmouseover="this.src='./images/Bannerc-3.png'" 
            onmouseout="this.src='./images/Banner-2.png'"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery;

```
$(document).ready(function){
    var $xMove = window.width - 1000
    var $mobile = $('.mobile')
    if(window.width > 1000){
        $($mobile).animate({
            left: "+=" + $xMove
        })
    }
}
$(window).resize(function){
    var $xMove = window.width - 1000
    var $mobile = $('.mobile')

    if(window.width > 1000){
        $($mobile).animate({
            left: "+=" + $xMove 
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var windowsize = $(window).width();
          if (windowsize > 1000)
          {
              //do this
              //do that..
          }
          else
          {
              //do this
              //do that..
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the image a static size? If so, wrap it in a div, set position to relative, and absolutely position the buttons.

If you create a JS fiddle I'd be able to show you by example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W67CL/. I don't have the images uploaded online quite yet. I could throw em' onto imgur if that'd help out more.

Positioning them that hasn't worked for me thus far.